# JavaScript getCurrentPosition() returning error code 3 on *some* Androids but not iOS or other Androids

Tags: javascript, android, web, geolocation

I have a simple website. I cannot retrive the geolocation of a phone.
getCurrentPosition() has three possible error codes, Code 1 implies a user permissions issue.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

What settings of Android will report Error Code 1: User Denied Geolocation?

Code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){}, 
    function(e){alert('Error Code ' + e.code + ': ' + e.message);},
    {  enableHighAccuracy: true,  timeout: 5000,  maximumAge: 0});
```

I have checked the following settings already and they look ok:

- Internet Browser > Settings > Advanced Settings > Website Settings (it's blank)
- Settings > Location Settings > On

What other settings could result in this User Denied? Or is it not a settings thing on the phone? No prompt seems to appear *ever* to allow the user to allow permissions.

It works fine on iOS, some Androids. Seems to fail on built in browser, and the chrome browser.